# How to detect if this post is a woocommerce product?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Let's say I have post has the ID 243. Is there a function that detects if this is a woocommerce product or no. maybe the function return true/false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use Condition for check product or post

```
if(is_product() && get_the_id() == 243) {
    //do stuff
}else{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks to this I also used 
has_term( '', 'product_cat', post_id)

Comment: Note that `is_product - Returns true when viewing a single product.` — This is a loop function, not for checking an ID out of context.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the official WooCommerce internal function:

```
$product = wc_get_product($id);
var_dump($product);
```

This will yield `empty($product) === True` if the `$id` is not a product.